# TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API for string

Tags: python

```
rootPath = arg
pattern = '*.*'
f = open('facad.csv', 'w')
fname = 'facad.csv'


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        if 'SETQ' and 'findfile' and 'getvar' in open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'rb').read():
            data = os.path.join(root, filename)+", ACAD_LSP\n"
            f.write(data)
        elif 'base.dcl' in open(os.path.join(root, filename)).read():
            data = os.path.join(root, filename)+", ACAD_LSP\n"
            f.write(data)
        elif 'vl-file-copy' in open(os.path.join(root, filename)).read():
            data= os.path.join(root, filename)+", ACAD_LSP\n"
            f.write(data)
        elif 'FAS4-FILE' in open(os.path.join(root, filename)).read():
            data = os.path.join(root, filename)+", ACAD_FAS\n"
            f.write(data)
        elif 'Autodesk' in open(os.path.join(root, filename)).read():
             data = os.path.join(root, filename)+", ACAD_LSP\n"
             f.write(data)
        elif 'acad.lsp' in open(os.path.join(root, filename)).read():
             data = os.path.join(root, filename)+", ACAD_LSP\n"
             f.write(data)
f.close()
```

I am getting this error:

```
C:\Python33>python D:\python\ftacad.py G:\ginipig\acad_and_lisp\ACAD_samples 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "D:\python\ftacad.py", line 62, in <module>
  main() 
File "D:\python\ftacad.py", line 40, in main
  if 'SETQ' and 'findfile' and 'getvar' in open(os.path.join(root, filename),' rb').read(): 
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

I have various types of files to search.
Code not running only in 3.x.
Runs fine below this version of Python.

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: You need to give us the **full** traceback of your exception; it means you need to pass in bytes, not a unicode string.

Comment: Also, you have a problem with your first `if` condition; your code is *not* working as designed even in Python 2. See [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125)

Comment: You are also reading the each file *six times*, making your code *exceedingly slow*. Read the file just once.

Comment: can someone give me write use of first if statement where i checked 3 conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.x

```
rootPath = arg
pattern = '*.*'
f = open('facad.csv', 'w')
fname = 'facad.csv'


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        fullname = os.path.join(root, filename)
        with open(fullname, 'rb') as infile:
            data = infile.read()
        output = None

        if b'SETQ' in data and b'findfile' in data and b'getvar' in data:
            output = "ACAD_LSP"
        elif b'base.dcl' in data:
            output = 'ACAD_LSP'
        elif b'vl-file-copy' in data:
            output = 'ACAD_LSP'
        elif b'FAS4-FILE' in data:
            output = 'ACAD_FAS'
        elif b'Autodesk' in data:
            output = 'ACAD_LSP'
        elif b'acad.lsp' in data:
            output = 'ACAD_LSP'

        if output:
            f.write("{0}, {1}\n".format(fullname, output).encode(utf-8'))
f.close()
```

A shorter clear code is better. DRY principle: Don't repeat yourself.